# SVG clippath working in all browsers except Safari

Tags: svg

My SVG with clippath on an image is working on all browsers except for Safari. I've tried implementing the clippath with `-webkit` but that does not make any difference. Below is a JSfiddle for reference.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbz3ao7p/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works on Safari too if you close the image tag and use `xlink:href` instead of `href`.

```
<image width="100%" height="100%" style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-02);" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xlink:href="https://source.unsplash.com/random" />
```